# How can I use Perl to delete a row in an Excel file?

Tags: perl

I have to delete a line which contain zero in two columns. How do I do that?

Comment: Punctuation, capital letters. Furthermore, do not just ask for code, but show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

No, but I can point you in the right direction.

The [Win32::OLE module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-OLE) can help with scripting Excel and other Windows apps in Perl. I'm assuming you have Excel installed.

Comment: Here's a great summary of all the commands to manipulate Excel from perl via Win32:OLE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613878/list-of-perl-commands-to-manipulate-windows-excel-with-win32ole-module

Answer (score 1):

You can also use CPAN modules [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/) and [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~kwitknr/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.2603/ParseExcel.pm) Perl modules to manipulate excel.