# HowTo write a formula in cell using perl WIN32::OLE

Tags: excel, perl, formula, win32ole

I try to insert a formula `=IF(D2="";"";COUNTIF(D:D;D2))` in an Excel worksheet.
Here is the code I'm trying:

```
$WorkSheet->Cells($Row2Use,'L')->{Formula} = "=IF(D".$Row2Use."=\"\",\"\",COUNTIF(D:D,D".$Row2Use.")"; # =IF(D2="";"";COUNTIF(D:D;D2))
```

I also tried using `{Value}` instead of `{Formula}` without success!
What did I wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of Perl commands to manipulate Windows Excel with Win32::OLE module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613878/list-of-perl-commands-to-manipulate-windows-excel-with-win32ole-module)

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613878/list-of-perl-commands-to-manipulate-windows-excel-with-win32ole-module

Comment: Yes, could be, and of course I saw and read this too.
So th emethod I use with `{Formula}` is right, but whi is my cell empty at the end and I don't see an error like syntax error popping up!

Comment: or mutst i Use `Range` instead of `Cell`?

Comment: I am really not sure...I don't have a windows machine to try this out on, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following works for me. Code taken and modified from the link given by  xxfelixxx.

```
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const "Microsoft Excel";
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;


my $Excel = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application') || Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit');

$Excel->{Visible} = 1;

my $Book = $Excel->Workbooks->Add;
my $Sheet = $Book->Activesheet;

$Sheet->Range("A1")->{Value} = 1;
$Sheet->Range("A2")->{Value} = 1;
$Sheet->Range("A3")->{Formula} = "=SUMA(R[-2]C:R[-1]C)";
```

Comment: Ok, but this does not follow what was given: or use `Formula` with `A1`...`An` notation or use `FormulaR1C1` with relative positions of the cells

Comment: I tried $Sheet->Range("D3")->{Formula} = '=IF(D2="";"";COUNTIF(D:D;D2))'; - seems to work

Comment: If I use Cells instead of Range I get an exception.

Comment: ... reading carefully your post, I realized I missed a ")" at the end of the formula.
I would expect to get an error code here...