# perl WIN32::OLE - HowTo move Excel Worksheet (or change position)

Tags: perl, winapi, move, ole, worksheet

In the article [List of Perl commands to manipulate Windows Excel with Win32::OLE module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613878/list-of-perl-commands-to-manipulate-windows-excel-with-win32ole-module) it is mentioned how to add an Excel WorkSheet before or after an existing WorkSheet!

I want to move, so change the position of an existing WorkSheet, before or after an other WorkSheet. How can I achieve this? Is it just to replace the `add` in `$Book->Worksheets->Add({After => $workbook->Worksheets($workbook->Worksheets->{Count})});` by `move` (or `copy` if I want to copy)?

thank you for your hints!
Regards
Laurent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Worksheet.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheet-move-method-excel) method with the After attribute

I am not a perl specialist, but the syntax should be:

```
$Book->Worksheets("Sheet1")->Move({After => $workbook->Worksheets($workbook->Worksheets("Sheet2"))});
```

Comment: Sorry for no comment!
 I have to try this! I did not get the chance until now... I keep you informed

Comment: Hello
The "Move" method works as you described it.. Thank you for the hint!